# Decomposition groups of non-prime ideals

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

In the Galois theory/algebraic number theory textbooks and lecture notes I've seen, the decomposition group and decomposition field are always defined for prime ideals. Is there a more general theory of decomposition groups that is defined for ideals which may not be prime? What properties still hold in that more general situation? Any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the decomposition group is that it captures local information about the relevent extension at the corresponding prime. In order to "generalize" something you might at least want to have some idea of what you want to achieve. For example, if you take a Galois extension $L/K$ and an ideal $I$ fixed by $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$, then the "decomposition group" of $I$ is then $G$. If you take a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ which splits completely in $K$ (they exist), and you take the ideal $I$ to be the product $I = \prod_{H} \sigma \mathfrak{P}$ for $\sigma$ running over a subgroup $H$ and for  any prime $\mathfrak{P}$ in $L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$, then the "decomposition group" of $I$ is $H$.

Comment: If $N(I),N(J)$ are coprime then $D_{IJ} = D_I\cap D_J$, and the action of $G$ permuting the primes above $p$ is given by $G/\cap_j D_{P_j}$, any subgroup of which gives a pair $I,D_I$. So it amounts to make correspond $\cap_j D_{P_j}$ with the ramification and  $Frob_p$ data of $p$.

Comment: The inertia subgroups are interesting too, particularly the automorphisms acting trivially on $O_K/P_j^i$ for each $i$

Comment: @reuns This is the kind of thing I was after! Do you know of any references/notes detailing similar observations?